# Evaluating double integral by change in variable.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

Evaluate the following integral by changing to polar coordinates:
$\iint x dxdy$, where $0\leq x \leq y$ and $0 \leq y \leq 1$.
Above integral can be evaluated directly without changing the variables. I am getting the answer $\frac{1}{6}$. But I have to evaluate it by changing in polar coordinates. So let $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$. Then $dxdy=rdrd\theta$. But what will be the limits on $r$ and $\theta$ ?

Comment: You want the region between the lines y=x and y=0 and your radius is going between 0 and 1. Try drawing it out and see what u get

Comment: @HenryLee I think the limit of $\theta $ will be $\frac{\pi}{4}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. I am not sure whether I am correct or not and I have no idea for $r$.

Comment: @HenryLee I drew the region and the limits of r will  be $0\leq r \leq \frac {1}{\sin\theta}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Draw the region is key to understand the integral. If you do the graph you will find $$\frac{\pi}{4}\leq \theta\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$$ and $$0\leq y\leq 1$$
$$0\leq r \text{sin}(x)\leq 1$$
$$0\leq r\leq\frac{1}{\text{sin}(x)}$$

Comment: How $0\leq r \ leq 1$?

Comment: @Mathfun, remember $r=\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}$ and $0\leq x\leq y\leq 1$

Comment: I drew the region and the limits of r will  be $0\leq r \leq \frac {1}{\sin\theta}$

Comment: @Mathfun, you are right.  I made a mistake.  you can even get without drawing the graph. I fixed